# On hover display multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Basically, if you run this code, you will see that if you hover your mouse on the image, another image will display.

```html
<a href="#" ><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_X62nO_2U7lI/TLXWTYY4jJI/AAAAAAAAAOA/ZATU2XJEedI/s1600/profile-empty-head.gif" 
onmouseover="this.src=' http://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2013/10/24/101141614-79493992.530x298.jpg?v=1396026765'" 
onmouseout="this.src=' http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_X62nO_2U7lI/TLXWTYY4jJI/AAAAAAAAAOA/ZATU2XJEedI/s1600/profile-empty-head.gif '"  /></a>
```

What I need is that: when you hover your mouse, 10 other images will start showing consecutively instead of 1 only (while the mouse is hovered, they will keep looping). The images would be specified in the javascript method.

Many websites use this, to preview a video; when a user hovers on the video, many thumbs from the video will show to preview it. How can achieve it the most simple and efficient way?

Comment: may be this will help you..
http://buildinternet.com/2011/09/cycle-through-images-on-hover-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this
HTML

```
<a href="#" ><img id="imageSlide" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_X62nO_2U7lI/TLXWTYY4jJI/AAAAAAAAAOA/ZATU2XJEedI/s1600/profile-empty-head.gif"/></a>
```

In js file

```
var timer = null;
$('#imageSlide').mouseover(function)
{
   var count = 0
   timer = setInterval(function()
   {
       //code to change the image source every time based on the count
       count++;
   },1000);
}

$('#imageSlide').mouseout(function)
{
    clearInterval(timer);
    //code to change the image source
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b92c297t/1/

---

html:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023210/on-hover-display-multiple-images/28025657#28025657" id="myA">
    Image:
</a>
```

---

js:

```
var src_images = [
    "http://www.superwallpapers.com.br/fotos-gratis/novas-fotos-de-paisagens02.jpg",
    "http://wallpaper.ultradownloads.com.br/278810_Papel-de-Parede-Paisagem-da-Suica_1920x1200.jpg",
    "http://sergiorochareporter.com.br/wp-content/uploads/imagens-imagem-paisagem-e03050.jpg",
    "http://www.capaparafacebook.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/paisagem38-712x264.jpg"
];

var l = src_images.length;

$.each(src_images, function(key, value){
    $("#myA").append("<img src='"+value+"' class='hide' />");
});

$("#myA img:first-child").toggleClass("hide");

var change_images;

$("#myA").hover(function(){
    change_images = setInterval(change, 1000);
}, function(){
    clearInterval(change_images);
});

function change(){
    var img = $("#myA").find("img:not(.hide)");
    img.addClass("hide");
    var nextImg = img.next("img");
    if( img[0] === $("#myA").find("img").last()[0] )
        nextImg = $("#myA").find("img").first();
    nextImg.removeClass("hide");
}
```

---

css:

```
a {
    background-color: #ddf;
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #33f;
}
img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

---

You can add how many source images you want in the array...
You can implement a bit more too... but it is working... hope it helps

Comment: I did a fiddle... check if it is what you need